# Opposite of "trick film"

Tags: antonyms, cinema

What's the term for the opposite of a "trick film" (animated or computer-generated film), i.e. a "real" film shot on a real location with real objects and people?

Answer (score 4):

This is usually termed [***live action***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live-action) regardless of whether it's filmed entirely in a studio, or the film crews go to where the action is supposedly happening and film it there.  In the latter case, it is also said to be filmed [***on location***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_shooting). A film (or TV show) may be ***live action***, but not ***on location***; most of *Star Trek* would fall under this classification. The original film of *The Taking of Pelham 1-2-3* (with Walter Matthau) was filmed in part in the New York City subways; those scenes were ***on location***.

Comment: Do you have any proof that it is 'live action' and 'on location'?